# Selecting the Number of Bins in a Histogram: A Decision Theoretic Approach

Tags: histogram

I am attending a course about Python and as supplementary readings for the lesson about plotting histograms the Professor suggested the following article: [Selecting the Number of Bins in a Histogram: A Decision Theoretic Approach](http://users.stat.umn.edu/%7Egmeeden/papers/hist.pdf)

From what I understood, the conclusion is that the number of bins could be chosen by minimizing the function (2.5) at the bottom of page 8.

#### My question: have you ever applied this specific approach and when should it be preferred to Freedman-Diaconis rule?

Comment: ¿In what context are you planning to use the histogram? E.g., for presentation purposes, or for a subsequent analysis (using the frequency bins and counts)

Comment: Good point! What do you think about considering the two scenarios? 1) presentation purposes / decision-making; 2) subsequent analysis (using the frequency bins and counts)

Comment: Especially, for presentation purpose the number of bins should be determined by the trade off between two parameters: clearness and descriptive power. In fact, with `bins = number of samples` you get a more clear picture but every data point ends up being unique